# How to do Encode and encrypt the multiple number?

Tags: python, json, encryption, encode

I have JSON data as below:

```
{
    "Body": {
        "AccNum": [
            "000405010255",
            "000405010310",
            "000405009777",
            "000401109537",
            "000401113460",
            "000401116861",
            "001805015288",
            "628801537715",
            "000319000184",
            "000401193586",
            "000405111139",
            "000405501186",
            "000760004994",
            "000805015689",
            "000813001320",
            "001105024982",
            "001801080623",
            "001810042371",
            "001825075268",
            "004214109637",
            "004214109638",
            "010310000278",
            "032501004151",
            "044205008102",
            "105701000275",
            "630010075140"
        ]
    }
}
```

Now i have to fetch the number one by one and hide the first 8 digits of the number and then encode the number and after encrypt the number. How can i do this part for all numbers? Like ex. first, it'll fetch the first number then it'll hide the first 8 digits of that number after it will encode the number and encrypt the number after it will fetch the second number it will process the same. for all numbers, i have to process like this.

Comment: what do you mean by hide?

Comment: @Yash it will hide the first 8 digit number like ex: this is the number "000405010255" so it will replace the first 8 digit number with "X" like "XXXXXXXX0255".

Comment: ok.. and which encryption? you can use modules like json and list for traversing and hashlib for hashing.

Comment: The encryption part I'll manage. i just want to extract the number one by one and replace the number with "X" as i explained above. and i don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use json module and list slicing. you are basically concatenating X 8 times with other 4 digits of your list item

```
import json
a={
    "Body": {
        "AccNum": [
            "000405010255",
            "000405010310",
            "000405009777",
            "000401109537",
            "000401113460",
            "000401116861",
            "001805015288",
            "628801537715",
            "000319000184",
            "000401193586",
            "000405111139",
            "000405501186",
            "000760004994",
            "000805015689",
            "000813001320",
            "001105024982",
            "001801080623",
            "001810042371",
            "001825075268",
            "004214109637",
            "004214109638",
            "010310000278",
            "032501004151",
            "044205008102",
            "105701000275",
            "630010075140"
        ]
    }
}
a["Body"]["AccNum"]=["X"*8 + x[8:] for x in a["Body"]["AccNum"]]
print(json.dumps(a))
```